# Recommendation on AD organization

Tags: performance, security, active-directory, ldap

I have a scenario where security is mandated to be handled in Active Directory.

I have thousands of users.
I have hundreds of thousands of contracts.
I have 6 different roles that any user can have on any given contract.

The original implementation (don't blame me, I just got here!) created a new security group for each contract-role. As soon as users were assigned to the appropriate groups (1800+ in some cases) login and LDAP query performance for those users became unbearable (11+ minute logins).

So I'm looking for a better option, how would you tackle this association? Other ways to structure the relationship? Custom classes/attributes? Thoughts?

Comment: Do the groups actually provide permissions to anything, or are they simply for record keeping?

Comment: It is effectively permissions. The code in question checks to see if a user is a member of a group that is identified by the contract and role that the user is attempting to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to rethink, a quick search in the Active Directory scalability limits documentation shows this:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/active-directory-maximum-limits-scalability(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_Groups

> Security principals (that is, user, group, and computer accounts) can be members of a maximum of approximately 1,015 groups. This limitation is due to the size limit for the access token that is created for each security principal. The limitation is not affected by how the groups may or may not be nested.

Comment: Yup, I saw that, which made me dig deeper. It appears that years back an API was created that points to a separate directory service (EDIR) that is capable of scaling to significantly larger volumes than AD is. 

In theory, by the expectations of the API developer, the performance impact is likely a poor implementation of the API. That the coder has inadvertently attempted to make thousands of unnecessary API calls. More investigation is required to see if that is the actual issue. But I'm still curious to know if there is a better way to handle this type of relationship in a directory service

Comment: @ThatRickGuy Very important to note, if you have an application that is querying AD directly to check group membership, you can use  Distribution Groups instead of Security Groups. They are essentially unlimited. Depending on how the application is implemented you might not even have to change it (or you might need to, but should be simple to do), and distrbution groups will not affect logins or anything else in windows because only security groups are returned as part of the login token.

Comment: @ThatRickGuy Failing that, replace your AD authentication system with a custom one that runs on SQL.